How Can You Detect Android Phone Homepage Chrome/Browser Launch?
You can quick-launch a webpage from the Android Phone Homepage by doing the following:

Open the site in Android Chrome
Tap the menu (3 dots at upper right) and choose "Add to Home Screen"
It will prompt you to change the title. Tap Ok

What javascript can I write on a webpage to detect that launch from the Android Phone Homepage?
Are there similar quick-launch options on an I-Phone, and how can they be detected?

This doesn't sound like something that would be detectable, unless it sets a specific document.referrer. Browsers don't have a variable that says how they were launched.
